# How to set superaccount when installing postgres 9.2 as extract-only

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to install postgres enterprise db on windows. I give an option file with parameters for installation. But instead of installing as a windows application, I want to just extract the binaries. I have this following option:

```
superaccount=dbadmin
```

But when I specify `extract-only=yes` option, the above parameter is ignored. I created data directory, and started pg_ctl manually. So when I open pgadmin3 in bin folder and connect to it, I see that there is no login role "dbadmin". Instead the default admin user is my system user account name. So I manually created this role and tried to delete the default system role. When I try to delete, I get the error "ERROR: cannot drop role  because it is required by the database system".

So my question is this: Can I just extract the binaries for postgres and set the default db user name to "dbadmin" role? Or am I missing something here?

**Edit:** Also, when we install normally, we give a port number. But when I just extract the binaries, tools like pg_ctl, psql etc look for the default port (5432). How do I set these defaults when I just extract the binaries?

**Edit 2:** I am trying to do everything the installer usually does except a few other things like creating registry entries, start menu shortcuts etc.

Comment: The default superuser and the port are defined when you run `initdb`. Read the manual for that tool, it's all explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it working now. Basically I was trying to do everything postgres installer usually does except making registry entries and shortcuts. So, I found out what the installer does by looking at the temp\install-postgres.log file. It basically executes a bunch of vb scripts. After extracting the binaries, you need to execute the following scripts in this order. These scripts are found in \installer\server.

- vcredist_x64
- initcluster.vbs
- startupcfg.vbs
- startserver.vbs
- loadmodules.vbs

All these scripts need command line arguments. Do a normal install, then look at the install-postgres.log file to find out how to execute these.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of "just extracting the binaries", consider [using the .zip bundle](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload).

You need to be willing to read the documentation if you're going to bypass the installer. See:

- [`initdb`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)
- [client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)

You can specify the superuser name at initdb-time, it's shown in the manual linked above.

If you want to set a different default port for the tools you can set the `PGPORT` env var, but please don't do that. Just specify the port explicitly for every invocation of your tools on the command line or override `PGPORT` before each invocation. That way you won't tread on a user's existing installation of PostgreSQL. If they install your app and suddenly all their PostgreSQL tools point at a different database they will *not* be happy with you.